# Sandhyavandanam and Maadhiyanikam

Tags: vedas, shiva, advaita, vaishnavism, sandhyavandanam

Many people in this current world are not able to do Trikala Sandhyavandanam.

In that case, I have heard people saying the Prata Sandhyavandanam and Maadhiyanikam can be done together.
Is it allowed or mentioned like that anywhere?

How come? Can someone please tell me?
Because, the mantras are different for both at certain sections.

Answer (score 3):

According to prayaschittha marga mentioned for office goers by Sri Chandrasekhara Paramacharya Garu

> Madhyahnika Sandhyavandanam can be performed 2 hours 24 minutes after
> sunrise that is called "sangava kala".

[Gayathri and Sandhyavandanam](https://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part17/chap12.htm)

> Sangava kala - If daytime is divided into five parts, this will be the second part.

[Sangava kaalam](https://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part17/referp17.htm#SANGAVA%20-%20KALA)

If one is performing morning sandhyavandanam itself at a later time with parayaschitta arghyam then they can combine Pratah and Madhayhnika sandhyavandanam together.